# Is there a way to consistently click DevExtreme elements with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, devextreme

I am unable to consistently click these elements without using a `cy.wait(1000)` in combination with a `.click().click()` on the element

I have tried doing an assertion-action chain like this: `.should('be.visible').click()` but that hasn't worked either, I still get the "detached from the DOM" error.

Any ideas?